# Laravel - code optimization for selecting column differences within 7 days

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have this code. Finally, the player is returned with the **levelDifference** attribute for every day 7 days back. Could this be optimized to one sql query instead of looping and doing 7 queries?

Also, I would like to know if you can omit withMin and withMax and just get the difference between the smallest and the largest lvl on a given day?

```php
$days = collect();

        foreach (range(1, 7) as $dayNumber) {
            $data = $game->players()
                ->withMin(
                    ['statistics' => fn ($query) => $query->whereDate('created_at', '=', now()->subDays($dayNumber))],
                    'level'
                )
                ->withMax(
                    ['statistics' => fn ($query) => $query->whereDate('created_at', '=', now()->subDays($dayNumber))],
                    'level'
                )
                ->get();

            $filtered = $data->filter(function ($item) {
                return $item->statistics_min_level && $item->statistics_max_level;
            });

            $dayStats= $filtered->values()->map(function ($item) {
                $item->levelDifference = $item->statistics_max_level - $item->statistics_min_level;

                return $item;
            });

            $days->put(
                $dayNumber,
                $dayStats
            );
        }

        return $days;
```

Table schema

```php
Schema::create('player_statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('player_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('level');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('player_id')->references('id')->on('players')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->index(['player_id', 'created_at']);
        });
```

Sample expected response

```json
[
   {
     ...user1,
     statistics: [
       1: { // 1 a day back
         "minLevel": 5,
         "maxLevel": 10
         "levelDifference": 5,
       },
       2: { // 2 is 2 days back
         "minLevel": 10,
         "maxLevel": 20
         "levelDifference": 10,
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     ...user2,
     statistics: [
       1: {
         "minLevel": 5,
         "maxLevel": 10
         "levelDifference": 5,
       },
       2: {
         "minLevel": 10,
         "maxLevel": 20
         "levelDifference": 10,
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: we definitely need to know your table(s) schema(s).

Comment: @ths I added a table schema

Comment: would you  please add an output illustrating the wanted structure of the data after performing the database call.

Comment: @ths I updated my post. What do you think about it?